# Is setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin of a localhost server to * dangerous?

Tags: node.js, networking

The title says it all, a '*' allows requests from every address, so is it possible that someone outside of the network is able to send one to the localhost server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just allows any web site run off any domain to use Ajax from its own web pages to make requests to your server.  Sometimes, this is something you want (you're offering some sort of service that you want other sites to be able to access from their web pages) and sometimes this is not something you want (you don't want other web sites to freely use your client-side APIs).

Keep in mind that this has nothing to do with your core security because only requests coming from a browser's Javascript actually respect same origin restrictions.  Any other server or script on the internet is not bound by those restrictions at all.

> is it possible that someone outside of the network is able to send one to the localhost server

The `access-control-allow-origin` has nothing to do with whether or not some outside agent can send requests to your localhost server.  That will be determined by other security mechanisms such as firewalls and routers.  In other words, if your server is not currently reachable from the general internet, then that won't change because you do or don't configure `access-control-allow-origin`.  Or, if your server is reachable, that won't change if you do or don't configure `access-control-allow-origin`.

The only thing that can be modified by that is whether Javascript from a browser's web page is allowed (by the browser) to contact your server (if it is otherwise reachable).  Other outside agents (servers, scripts or programs not running in a browser) are not impacted at all by the `access-control-allow-origin` setting.